# Ember: WillTransition does not fire when going directly to URL

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-cli

I need to perform authorization on what routes the user is allowed to access. According to the documentation for ember i should use 'WillTransition'

http://guides.emberjs.com/v1.11.0/routing/preventing-and-retrying-transitions/

> When a transition is attempted, whether via {{link-to}}, transitionTo, **or a URL change**, a willTransition action is fired on the currently active routes. This gives each active route, starting with the leaf-most route, the opportunity to decide whether or not the transition should occur.

So i put this code in my application route to try and first log all the times its called.

```
   actions: {
        willTransition: function(){
            console.log('Transitioning');
        }
    }
```

This works fine when i'm inside my app and then click to transition to another route. But if i go directly to a protected route it doesn't fire. Ex. /myapp/protected/route

But with the debug flag

```
NV.APP.LOG_TRANSITIONS = true;
```

set i get these logs inside the console. Even when the 'WillTransition' event hasn't fired.

```
Preparing to transition from 'myapp.index' to 'myapp.protected.index'
Transitioned into 'myapp.protected.index'
```

So i go and look at the log event in the ember source and i see

```
/**
  Handles notifying any listeners of an impending URL
  change.
   Triggers the router level `willTransition` hook.
   @method willTransition
  @private
  @since 1.11.0
*/
willTransition: function (oldInfos, newInfos, transition) {
  run['default'].once(this, this.trigger, "willTransition", transition);

  if (property_get.get(this, "namespace").LOG_TRANSITIONS) {
    Ember['default'].Logger.log("Preparing to transition from '" + EmberRouter._routePath(oldInfos) + "' to '" + EmberRouter._routePath(newInfos) + "'");
  }
},
```

Right above the line that writes the console log is a line that looks like it is supposed to fire the event, but its not reaching my code. What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Authorization check it might be better directly on the routes, in the beforeModel function.

You can create a mixin and implement it on every route

```
App.Auth =  Ember.Mixin.create({
   beforeModel: function(){
       if(!this.get('userAuthorized')){
           //prevent entering and go to login route
           this.transitionTo('login');
           //show msg to user that it needs access
       }
   }
});
```

You can implement the mixin on routes like this

```
App.UserStuffRoute = Ember.Route.extend(App.Auth,{ });
```